# Question on comparision of integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this integral

$$\int_0^1 U(M)dx\ge \int_0^1 U(N)dx$$

for any function U.

According to this integral, can I say that $U(M)\ge U(N)$?

Is this true?

——————-

Edit:

If real integral is as follows:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x g(z)M(z)dz dx\ge \int_0^1 \int_0^x h(z)N(z)dzdx$$

Then similarly $U(M)=\int_0^x g(z)M(z)dz \ge \int_0^x h(z)N(z)dz=U(N)$ Can I say this?

Comment: So $U(M)$ and $U(n)$ are just numbers that don't depend on $x$? If so, then obviously yes - the left side *is* $U(M)$ and the right side *is* $U(N)$. If they are functions of $x$, then no.

Comment: @user296602 thank you for your reply. I add some edits. Then I cannot say the same thing in the second integral of the edit? Is it?

Comment: And one one question, which theorem we can say this? @user296602 thank you for your helps

Comment: In general, $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx > \int_0^1 g(x) \, dx$ does **not** let you say anything about comparing $f$ and $g$ pointwise. Take $f(x) = 100x$ and $g(x) = 1 - x$ for a simple case.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot say this. What you obtain is that $$\int_0^1\int_0^x\left\{g(z)M(z)-h(z)N(z)\right\}\,dz\,dx\ge0$$What this tells you is that the total integral (area / region) is positive. But this doesn't guarantee that for some value of $z$, that the function dips into the negative range.

Comment: Okay thank you so much:)